# How can I add header every location if query exist Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have two url

http://localhost/?shop=test

http://localhost/login?shop=test

first url is working. But second url coming 404 nginx page. how can I fix this problem. I want to every location come header if exist shop query

```
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        listen [::]:8081 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                if ( $arg_shop ) {
                        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors https://$arg_shop";
                }
                root /home;
                index index.html;
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `if` inside a `location`, [it doesn't work the way you expect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). Try moving the `if` block one level up into the `server` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith can you give answer? I dont undestand completly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `if` inside a `location`, is that [it doesn't work the way you expect](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

You can [use a `map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) to define the value of the `add_header` directive. If the argument is missing or empty, the header will not be added.

For example:

```
map $arg_shop $csp {
    ""      "";
    default "frame-ancestors https://$arg_shop";
}
server {
    ...

    add_header Content-Security-Policy $csp;

    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it is work like that so healthy. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed like that

```
server {
        listen 8081 default_server;
        listen [::]:8081 default_server;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                error_page 404 = @error_page;

                if ( $arg_shop ) {
                        add_header "Content-Security-Policy" "frame-ancestors https://$arg_shop";
                }

                root /home;
                index index.html;
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }

        location @error_page {
                add_header "Content-Security-Policy" "frame-ancestors https://$arg_shop";
                root /home;
                index index.html;
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$query_string;
        }
}
```